# Laravel 5 + WordPress: routes using the laravel front-end

Tags: wordpress, laravel

I'm working in a project based on Laravel 5 and my users will have their own pages: domain.com/user-page-slug (Route: /{user-page-slug}

After the user login in the system he will have the settings related to my project but I'm planning to give him the WordPress back-end then they can update their own pages and posts and for the front-end (using the route above) I want to render the WordPress theme selected.

For the rest of the system I'll use Laravel.

Do you know if it is possible?

Comment: Put Wordpress in it's own directory - e.g. /admin/ - and then use Laravel to define any routes other than /admin/ - e.g. /user-page-slug.  I believe that you will eventually find it necessary to give more structure to your slugs and do something like /user/user-page-slug.

Comment: Hi Dave, I'm thinking now to put only the back-end (admin) to work, then I'll connect the user in my system with the respective Wordpress user account. Finally for the front end I'll use the Wordpress functions and build my own theme with Laravel blade.